Boot Linux with rootfs in ram with uboot
On my embedded devices, using RPi 4, I want to boot linux without SD card used. My idea is, with uboot, I will create rootfs partition from .ext3 image, just like it's created on SD card, but not on SD, but somewhere in ram. I have tried load .ext3 file with tftpboot 0x00800000 rootfs.ext3 and then pass kernel arguments root=/dev/ram0 rw initrd=0x00800000,300M ramdisk_size=307200. Kernel starts booting, but then fails on end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(1,0).
Are there any extra steps required to create ram disk, or is it bad fs format, or bad kernel arguments?
EDIT: I have tried build cpio.gz image, which should be common way to achieve this, but I have got Wrong Ramdisk Image Format and Ramdisk image is corrupt or invalid. Then I have tried processed it with mkimage -A arm -O linux -T ramdisk -C gzip -d ramdisk.cpio.gz uRamdisk, but I have just gut the first kernel panic again.

"using RPi 4, I want to boot linux without SD card used" - Not really possible AFAIK. You probably need at least the U-Boot image and environment files on SD card to boot the SBC. Then you need to load a kernel image and DT blob into memory either from the SD card or the network. Then there's various choices for the root filesystem. Ramdisk is deprecated; use instead ramfs, which is more efficient and flexible. You can populate the built-in initramfs with a cpio archive file during kernel boot. Your actions are vaguely described so corrective advice cannot be offered.

@sawdust, Yes, I know, uboot would be SD card. But kernel, dtb and rootfs would be on tftp and would be loaded to ram. I want running linux completely independent on SD card.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78082022/error-kernel-panic-not-syncing-no-working-init-found-try-passing-init-opti/78104771#78104771 for an example of booting Linux with an external cpio archive for the initramfs. Note that this method reuses the ramdisk boot scheme, so there are misleading messages mentioning "ramdisk". That example's 3 fatload commands can be replaced with tftpboot [loadAddress] [[hostIPaddr:]bootfilename] U-Boot commands. Note that the cpio archive can also be bundled/linked with the kernel image for a combined/single file.
